# How to fetch json values into custom Map format [Flutter]

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I got some works with displaying event to calendar from json. I can fetch the data but couldnt fetch it into my desired Map format.

I used below code..

```
...
Map<datetime, List> _events;

Future getdata() async {
    _events ={};
    final response = await http.get("http://192.168.1.15/sipjw/getData.php");
    jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

  for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        _events[DateTime.parse(jsonData[i]['tanggal'])] = [jsonData[i]['acara']];
       }
  }
```

and it will return value like below even the date is equal:

```
events: {
Datetime A : Event A
Datetime A : Event B
}
```

the problem is, I want to fetched it into Map variable like this. So each datetime get list of events.

```
Map<datetime, List> _events;

events: {
Datetime A : Event A, Event B, Event C
Datetime B : Event A, Event B
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `for` loop with:

```
for (var jsonElement in jsonData) {
  _events
      .putIfAbsent(
        DateTime.parse(jsonElement['tanggal']),
        () => [],
      )
      .add(jsonElement['acara']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DateTime is equal, including milliseconds, you can use:

```
Map<int, List> _events; //millisecondsSinceEpoch : List

///...
int millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTime.parse(jsonData[i]['tanggal']).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
if(_events[millisecondsSinceEpoch]==null){
    _events[millisecondsSinceEpoch] = [];
}
_events[millisecondsSinceEpoch].add(jsonData[i]['acara']);
```